# Want to play Handheld.Playfullscreenmovie after a delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm building an AR app for iOS using Unity. What I want to do is play multiple full screen videos after a delay - for example, app starts up, plays a full screen video after 5 mins, another one after 10 mins and so on.

I'm assuming doing this with handheld.playfullscreenmovie and a coroutine would be the best way, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've managed to get handheld.playfullscreenmovie to work on detection of an image target - but I want it to operate independently of that after a time delay. I've tried the following code attached to an empty game object but when I build it to the iPad nothing happens.

```
IEnumerator Example()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("river.m4v", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Hidden, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Docs:**

- [PlayFullScreenMovie](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html)
- [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

**Code:**

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(Example());
}

IEnumerator Example()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("river.m4v", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Hidden, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
}
```

**Note:**

> Use MP4 video formatted videos files, since mkv is not support by all devices, which could be the issue. also its best to use smaller sized files, since not all devices may have the required amount of memory required to store (stream) the video. see docs for more info.

Comment: The reason I was using m4v is that mp4 didn't seem to work at all with fullscreenvideo in iOS - m4v seemed to be the only file type that worked to call handheld.fullscreenmovie on detection of an image target

Comment: @JackThone [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/playing-videos-in-ios-and-android-devices.271467/) and [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html)